# SQL Server select parts, fill with 0 no result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables

- Location (Id, locationName)
- Inventory (productid, qty, locationid)

With the following data, I need to query to show all locations per productid, even when not in inventory table. example of records below.

Table `Location`

```
Id   Location Name
--------------------
1    Plant
2    Warehouse
3    Container
```

Table `Inventory`:

```
Productid  Qty    Locationid
-----------------------------
  45        30         1
  45        56         2
  3         15         1  
  3         50         3 
  15        25         3
```

Desired result for my query:

```
Productid    Qty    LocationName
---------------------------------
 45          30      Plant
 45          56      Warehouse
 45           0      Container
  3          15      Plant
  3           0      Warehouse
  3          50      Container
 15           0      Plant
 15           0      Warehouse
 15          25      Container
```

So far I have tried many different ways but no luck, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide sample script to generate data?

Comment: If you can provide your query, so we could apply fixes from there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT p.ProductId, 
       COALESCE(qty,0) AS qty,
       [Location Name]
FROM LOCATION l
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ProductId FROM Inventory) AS p
LEFT JOIN Inventory i ON l.Id = i.locationid AND p.Productid = i.Productid
ORDER BY Productid, [Location Name]
```

The query uses `CROSS JOIN` to get all possible combinations between locations and products.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1b0e6/12)

Answer (score 0):

Select y.*, isNull(z.Quantity,0) as Quantity
From 
(
    Select Location.*, x.ProductId
    From  Location,(Select Distinct ProductId From Inventory)  as x
) as y
Left Outer Join Inventory z ON y.Id = z.LocationId 
    and y.ProductId = z.ProductId